# I have a new NIBBI racing carburetor for my 212cc

Tags: carburetor, small-engine

I just bought a new NIBBI carburetor for my 212 cc predator motor and the old one only had one line which was the gas line and this one has three so I’m not sure what to do with them one of the lines is coming out of the bottom of the float bowl, and the other one appears to be be coming from out of the side I’ll leave the link for it below
NIBBI Motorcycle Carburetor PE26FL Own Flange 150CC-200CC Carburetor With Carburetor Jets Fit YAMAHA KAWASAKI SUZUKI Apollo Dirt Bike Mini Bike SSR TTR KYMCO SYM TAOTAO Scooter Moped Horizontal Engine https://a.co/d/4uZF8o9

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! T